# Kafka Consumer Group Rebalance and Group Coordinator dead

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I have been playing around with Kafka (1.0.0) for a couple of months and trying to understand how consumer group works. I have a single broker Kafka and I am using Kafka-Connect-Cassandra to consume messages from topics to database tables. I have 10 topics, all have just one partition and I have a Single Consumer Group with 10 Consumer instances (one for each topic).

While running this setup I sometimes see the following logs in kafka-connect console:

### 1:

```
[Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Marking the coordinator qa-server:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) dead (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:341)
[Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Discovered group coordinator qa-server:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:341)
[Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=connect-cassandra-sink-casb] Discovered group coordinator qa-server:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:341)


[Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Marking the coordinator qa-server:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) dead (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:341)
[Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=connect-cassandra-sink-casb] Marking the coordinator qa-server:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) dead (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:341)
[Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Discovered group coordinator qa-server:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:341)
[Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=connect-cassandra-sink-casb] Discovered group coordinator qa-server:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordi
nator:341)
[Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=connect-cassandra-sink-casb] Revoking previously assigned partitions [topic1-0, topic2-0, ....] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:341)
[Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=connect-cassandra-sink-casb] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:336)
[Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=connect-cassandra-sink-casb] Successfully joined group with generation 349 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:341)
[Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=connect-cassandra-sink-casb] Setting newly assigned partitions [topic1-0, topic2-0, ....] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:341)
```

After this it starts consuming messages and writes to Cassandra Tables.
This happens frequently on irregular intervals.

However, sometimes the connector stops and shuts down. Then it starts and consumes messages again. This is the log:

```
INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Marking the coordinator qa-server:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) dead (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:341)
INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Discovered group coordinator qa-server:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:341)
INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Marking the coordinator qa-server:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) dead (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:341)
INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Discovered group coordinator qa-server:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:341)

INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=cassandra-sink-casb-0} Committing offsets asynchronously using sequence number 42: {topic1-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1074, metadata=''}, topic2-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=112, metadata=''}, ...}} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:311)
INFO Rebalance started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1214)
INFO Stopping connector cassandra-sink-casb (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:304)
INFO Stopping task cassandra-sink-casb-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:464)
INFO Stopping Cassandra sink. (com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraSinkTask:79)
INFO Shutting down Cassandra driver session and cluster. (com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraJsonWriter:253)
INFO Stopped connector cassandra-sink-casb (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:320)
INFO Finished stopping tasks in preparation for rebalance (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1244)
INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:336)
INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Successfully joined group with generation 7 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:341)
INFO Joined group and got assignment: Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1-1dc56cda-ed54-4181-a5f9-d11022d8e8c3', leaderUrl='http://127.0.1.1:8083/', offset=8, connectorIds=[cassandra-sink-casb], taskIds
=[cassandra-sink-casb-0]} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1192)
INFO Starting connectors and tasks using config offset 8 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:837)
INFO Starting connector cassandra-sink-casb (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:890)
```

### 2:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: 
Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. 
This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, 
which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum
 size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:722)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:600)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1250)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.doCommitSync(WorkerSinkTask.java:299)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.doCommit(WorkerSinkTask.java:327)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.commitOffsets(WorkerSinkTask.java:398)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.closePartitions(WorkerSinkTask.java:547)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.access$1300(WorkerSinkTask.java:62)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask$HandleRebalance.onPartitionsRevoked(WorkerSinkTask.java:618)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinPrepare(ConsumerCoordinator.java:419)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:359)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:316)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1146)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1111)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.pollConsumer(WorkerSinkTask.java:410)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:283)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:166)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=connect-cassandra-sink-casb] Marking the coordinator qa-server:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) dead (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordi
nator:341)
INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=connect-cassandra-sink-casb] Discovered group coordinator qa-server:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordi
nator:341)
INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=connect-cassandra-sink-casb] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:336)
INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=connect-cassandra-sink-casb] Successfully joined group with generation 343 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:341)
INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=connect-cassandra-sink-casb] Setting newly assigned partitions [topic1-0, topic2-0,...] (org.apache.kafka.cl
ients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:341)
INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=cassandra-sink-casb-0} Committing offsets asynchronously using sequence number 155: {topic1-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=836, metadata=''}, topic2-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=86, metadata=''}, ...}} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:311)
```

Again sometimes Kafka-Connect starts consuming messages after the rebalance and sometimes it shuts down.

I have the following questions:

```
1) Why does Group Coordinator (Kafka Broker) dies?
```

I am looking into multiple Kafka-Configs to resolve these issues, like `connections.max.idle.ms`, `max.poll.records`, `session.timeout.ms` , `group.min.session.timeout.ms` and `group.max.session.timeout`.

I am not sure what the best configs would be for things to run smoothly.

```
2) Why does rebalance occurs?
```

I know group rebalance can occur on adding a new task, changing the task, etc. But I haven't changed anything. Sometimes Kafka Connect framework seem to handle the error a bit too aggressive and kills the connect tasks instead of carrying on working.

Comment: Looking at the logs, it seems like ur consumer is dying and rejuvenating again. How much time does ur record processing take? You can change max.poll.records and reduce it to a small value, if ur record processing is very slow.

Comment: and can u use a separate consumer group for each topic. Do these two things and let me know, how it goes.

Comment: @IndraneelBende I have tried `max.poll.records` in consumer properties and now consumer group re-balance doesn't occur. However `marking the coordinator dead` still occurs. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: what version is your client api for kafka? Going to look at code and see if can find a reason , why it could be happening.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not sure. How can I know?

Comment: U can check for the version of kafka connect Cassandra ur using, what is the kafka client api

Comment: I am using Confluent Platform 3.1.1 and Lenses Cassandra Sink 1.0

Comment: do u know which version of kafka client api the above use?

Comment: Actually, I have encountered same problem, same error log while using Apache Storm with Kafka spout. And we couldn't figure out the problem yet. We are working on the mentioned issue  but I'm sure the problem is related with Kafka client.

Comment: @EL323 For Apache Storm,  there is a fixed bug about mentioned issue. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-2494. As i understand, dead consumer detection was taking long time and this fix overcome this problem. So you can still work around this by setting a higher session timeout, and newer Kafka versions.